# is 随分 of a higher degree than なかなか (with positive verb)?

Tags: grammar, nuances

my dictionary shows both 随分 and なかなか (with positive verb) as **"very/considerably"**

I was wondering is it true that 随分 is of a higher *degree* than なかなか?

Like

> あんた**なかなか**勇敢だな。= 75%

and

> あんた**随分**勇敢だな。 = 85%?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. `なかなか` means mildly, moderately. The origin is `中中`, 'middle-middle'. It is lower in degree than `随分`.

---

Below is slightly technical.

Elaborating on rintaun's point, `なかなか` has another usage: used with a negative expression. There are words that can be only used within negative environments (and some other environments, subsumed under what are technically called downward entailment environments).

> **決して** 食べない  [Japanese example]
>   **全然** 食べない  [Japanese example]
>   おかず **しか** 食べない  [Japanese example]
>   He does not study **at all** [English example]
>   I am not paying **a red cent** [English example]

Sometimes, a word can be used either under this usage or under a different usage:

> He cannot eat **any**-thing. [Negative usage]
>   He can eat **any**-thing. [Different usage]

Depending on the usage, the scale differs. `なかなか` is an instance of such word. It has a usage that requires a negative environment.

> 彼は **なかなか** 食べない [Negative usage]
>   彼は **なかなか** よく食べる [Different usage]

In this negative usage, the degree of `なかなか` is stronger.

Comment: actually instead of 勇敢 i wanted to use 勇ましい because i thought 勇敢 was ungrammatical..
 is it more common to say あんたなかなか勇敢だな or あんたなかなか勇ましいだな ?

Comment: I feel like なかなか has more affinity with negative expressions, and ずいぶん with positive. I haven't really investigated this relationship though, just speaking from intuition.

Comment: @Pacerier `あんたなかなか勇敢だな` is fine. `あんたなかなか勇ましいだな` is wrong. It should be `あんたなかなか勇ましいな`. They sound almost the same.

Comment: I'm just nitpicking now, but the modern colloquial usage of ぜんぜん in positive environments may be worth noting as well (e.g. ぜんぜん大丈夫 as "just fine").

Comment: @rintaun I knew someone is going to say that. But that is really controversial. I personally hate it. It sounds like either you are trying to look young, or are uneducated. Probably attracting the reader's attention to your comment is sufficient, so I will just upvote your comment.